# How to data-bind checkbox value to Javascript object

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, 2-way-object-databinding

I am trying to set up 2-way data binding in Javascript for a simple form. I have been using the [databind](https://github.com/grnadav/databind) plugin by grnadav, but have been unable to get a (or multiple) checkbox values to bind to an object array. The data model, js binding and test output function are

```
// DataBind model
var model = {
  title: 'sample',
  cb: ['option', 'option', 'option']
}

// bind form
window.onload = function() {

  DataBind.bind( document.getElementById('form'), model );

};

// log data values
function sendForm(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(model));
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(model);
}
```

The HTML markup is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Checkbox Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="form">
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
      <td><input id="title" data-key="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkboxes</td>
      <td>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[0]" id="in-checkbox1" value="one" type="checkbox"/>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[1]" id="in-checkbox2" value="two" type="checkbox"/>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[2]" id="in-checkbox3" value="three" type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><pre id="data"></pre></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="Button" name="Submit" value="Continue" onclick="sendForm()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="DataBind.js"></script>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can only bind to objects not arrays, try:

```js
var model = {
  title: 'sample',
  cb: [{key:'option'}, {key:'option'}, {key:'option'}]
};
// bind form
window.onload = function() {
  DataBind.bind( document.getElementById('form'), model );
};
// log data values
function sendForm(){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(model));
  document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(model);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/grnadav/databind/0.4.x/src/DataBind.min.js"></script>
<table id="form">
    <tr>
      <td>Input</td>
      <td><input id="title" data-key="title"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Checkboxes</td>
      <td>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[0].key" id="in-checkbox1" value="one" type="checkbox"/>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[1].key" id="in-checkbox2" value="two" type="checkbox"/>
        <input name="checkbox-group" data-key="cb[2].key" id="in-checkbox3" type="checkbox"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><pre id="data"></pre></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="Button" name="Submit" value="Continue" onclick="sendForm()"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

You can add issue for that on [github](https://github.com/grnadav/databind/issues).

Comment: I tried using an array of objects, but that didn't work either... More importantly, the data result I need is an array of string values, not objects. I feel like it should be something that can be reasonably modified in the code. I'm just not sure how to do it.